# Ionic 2 Beta blank project not showing ionicons

Tags: ionic2, ionicons

I recently installed the Beta of Ionic 2 by typing the following

```
ionic start myproject blank --v2 --ts
```

which is going fine, going through the ionic 2 documentation, i want to add some icons using the code provided, like so

```
<ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
```

But when i view my project, it either shows just a black box, or nothing at all.

My package.json file also includes the following line

```
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
```

Im not sure what im missing,

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I had this problem as well and I just found out the solution. 
Make sure you have ionicons installed.


**If not** installed add the following to your package.json dependencies:

> **`ionicons": "3.0.0"`** and run **npm update**

After that, add this in your **`app.core.scss`** file in  under **`app/theme folder`**.

```
@import "/node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem migrating from Ionic 2 beta to 2.0.0-rc.5.
After looking into the starter [tutorial](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/tutorial/) source code, I realized that src/theme/variables.scss was missing this import:

```
@import "ionicons";
```